# Move the cursor to the right next cell, rather than the cell underneath

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I want to achieve with the code further down: If I use the RETURN key, the cell right next to the current cell should be selected, rather than the cell underneath. When I execute the code (i.e. I change between two different worksheets, the cursor moves from the current selected cell to the right next one. When then I use RETURN, I get the message as in the attached image: "Cannot run the macro 'PathToMacro\MacroName'!TRUE: The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled." What I want to achieve is this:
Change the behaviour of the RETURN key so that not the underneath cell, but the cell right to the currently selected cell is selected.

Please help with this. Thank you.

["Cannot run the macro 'PathToMacro\MacroName'!TRUE: The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omWZy.png)

```
Option Explicit
Sub getNextCell()
  activeCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Dim activeCell As Range
  Set activeCell = Selection
  Application.OnKey "{RETURN}", Cells(activeCell.row, activeCell.column + 1).Select
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.OnKey "{RETURN}", Cells(activeCell.row, activeCell.column + 1).Select
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
  Application.OnKey "{RETURN}"
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn’t there a setting for that in the excel preferences ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to my question:
The procedures are specific to the sheet.
As the sheet is entered, the cursor moves to the right
As the sheet changes to another sheet, regular behaviour is restored!

```
' move cursor to the right upon ENTER key
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
        Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight
    End Sub
 ' return to default behaviour
    Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
        Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlDown
    End Sub
```