# VBA code has unwanted impact on copy and paste action between sheets

Tags: excel, vba

The following code changes the default behavior for an Excel worksheet to move the cursor to the right, rather than down.

This code has a side effect: copying from this sheet (which includes the code) to another sheet does not work; for example: Copy from sheet1(which includes the code) columns A1 through A10 to sheet2 B2. I can do copy and paste on the same sheet as copying from sheet1 a1-a10 to b1.

Copy and paste action between all other sheets are not affected. When I remove this code, than the wanted behavior for copy and paste for Excel between this sheet and any other sheet is restored.

Here is the offending code:

```
' moving the cursor to the right rather than down
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight
End Sub
' move the cursor down
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlDown
End sub
```

Please also compare: [Move the cursor to the right next cell, rather than the cell underneath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72243611/move-the-cursor-to-the-right-next-cell-rather-than-the-cell-underneath?noredirect=1#comment127637482_72243611)

This is how this problem started!

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Please also compare: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72243611/move-the-cursor-to-the-right-next-cell-rather-than-the-cell-underneath?noredirect=1#comment127637482_72243611

Comment: It seems like changing `Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection` causes the copied selection to be lost. [Relevant](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0fb9cadf-d3ed-4913-8930-64a8fc72b187/why-excel-clipboard-is-cleared-after-com-excel-office-interop-call-eg). And [another](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/workbookdeactivate-clears-clipboard/5d010fb8-7787-440a-9214-23eb89ec17e0).

Comment: I think `worksheet_deactivate` clears it.

Comment: If you were only interested in values, then you could use value assignment instead of the clipboard, e.g. `Sheet2.Range("A1:A10").Value2 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").Value2`

Comment: BigBen: this was a perfect duplication of my question. Warcupine: I believe you are right. The clipboard is clearing with the worsheet_deactivate. Afterwards the past is not available even for the copying in the same sheet. SpectralInstance: Yes, this is a solution, but in my case, I was not so much interested in a VBA solution, but just for the purpose of copying and pasting during regular Excel use.

Comment: It seems that the worksheet_activate and worksheet_deactivate code both delete the clipboard content. Following Warcupine's suggestion I deleted the worksheet_deactivate code from my original sheet and implemented a worksheet_activate code for the two remaining sheets identical to my original worksheet_activate code (Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlDown). The result did not change. The clipboard content was not available after changing to the other worksheet after my implementation.